# Rearranging texts in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane, efxclipse

I am using Javafx. I have gridpane(1,2). My gridpane ends with buttons (1,2) and (0,2). I want to write something under these buttons. I added a text into gridpane. However, since my text's widht is longer than the buttons, the layout does not look nice and buttons are shifted. How can I solve this problem? How can I add label or text without shifting my layout. Here are the settings of my gridpane: `

```
gridPane.add(text1, 0, 0); 
gridPane.add(textField1, 1, 0); 
gridPane.add(text2, 0, 1);       
gridPane.add(textField2, 1, 1); 
gridPane.add(button1, 0, 2); 
gridPane.add(button2, 1, 2);

gridPane.setVgap(5); 
gridPane.setHgap(5);`
```

Comment: If it isn't otherwise required, you can use Scene Builder. It is much more easier.

Comment: I will check it. Thank you.

Comment: you can set absolute locations for your nodes, but it creates other issues down the road. Also check using CSS Stylesheets, which is possible in JavaFX

Comment: Could you set your text to span multiple columns to fix the issue?

Comment: You could use [Column Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html) or alternatively you could put you items in a container in your grid location

Comment: @benji2505 I will check it out later. But thank you for information :)

Comment: @Matt During the day, I have seen solutions like what you said. As I see now, it will work. Thanks man :)

Comment: @Zephyr Instead of that, I put my gridpane into the borderpane. It worked. Thanks a lot :)